# How do I complete one function fully before moving on to other function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Although I could find help on how to redirect pages but I could not find one which would match my situation.

I would like to fadeout the popup -- which has a form inside it -- before redirecting to the form's 'action' link.

I have the fadeout in separate function as that function is more complicated and is called by number of times.

My jquery code :

```
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        function(e){
            hidePopup()
                    ,function(e){
            window.location.href = $('form').attr('action');
        };};

    });

    //hiding popup
    function hidePopup(){
        $(".popup").fadeOut("slow");
    };
```

Comment: The way you have your code, the page will refresh. Doesn't matter if you close the modal box or not, it will still go back to what it was if the form submits to self. I don't see why you are bothering with this.

Comment: I did it coz' I would like to fadeout the popup before redirecting the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) accepts a callback function as second parameter. That callback is exectued after completely feaded out. So just use:

```
$(".popup").fadeOut("slow", function(){//Executes after faded out//});
```

In your code, I'd suggest you rewrite your `hidePopup` function

```
function hidePopup(callback){
    $(".popup").fadeOut("slow",callback);
};
```

And execute it like

```
hidePopup(function(){
    window.location.href = $('form').attr('action');
});
```

**Update** You can check if you have passed a valid callback with the following code:

```
function hidePopup(callback){
    if (typeof(callback) =='function')
        $(".popup").fadeOut("slow",callback);
    else
        $(".popup").fadeOut("slow");
};
```

It is a robust check that guarantees that you have passed a valid callback (well, as JS is not strictly-typed language you can't be sure that this function have the correct *signature*, but that's outside that question).

If you are absolutely sure you will always pass `callback` or `undefined` and you are lazy enough to wish typing 20 characters less, you could simplify `if (typeof(callback) =='function')` to just `if (callback)`. it will check that you have passed *something*. But that 's not a good practice (but popular though). :)

*Update 2:* `length` property of a function returns the number of it's arguments. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Comment: This animates the popout during submit. But it generates errors inside jquery when no arguments are passed, ie. doing fadeout without submit.
I slightly changed he hidePopup fn as below.

 //hiding popup
 function hidePopup(callback){
  if(callback == undefined){
      $(".backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
  }else{
      $(".backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow",callback);
  };
 };

Comment: Consider it as being your homework. :) I'll update the answer in a minute with some code to handle that errors.

Comment: I just discovered  `callback.length` too seems to do the trick somewhat. Is there a difference compared to using `typeof` ?

Comment: I think `length` is defined on arrays and `jQuery` objects. I'm not sure, but I think ordinary functions does not have `length` property. So it's not the same.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Updated the post.

Comment: Thanks very much. I guess that's be enough for me.